# How can i change my fileserver, without changing the files path?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server, file-sharing

I have one windows server 2012 R2, with a file share named "\SRV50\Files", and, i need to migrate all my files to another server (SRV100), but, i cant change all the files path. (I have another system, with all the paths loaded.. with more than 160.000 registers)

All the files are with that routes:
\SRV50\Files\File1.txt
\SRV50\Files\File2.txt
\SRV50\Files\File3.txt
...

I need to change physically the location of my files, without changing the paths..

(So the files will be on SRV100, but need to access as \SRV50\Files\File1.txt ...)

The server SRV50 will be shut down, keeping alive just the SRV100

Are any way i can achieve this? (I've asked chatGPT, and he says to use the DFS, but i cant use this.)

i've already tried changing the DNS "SRV50" poiting to the server "SRV100", but it only works for ping cmd, and not the file share.